# Python: error trying to delete a file that was generated to be sent an email attachment

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to delete 2 files that are created to be attached and be sent in an email.

The below code works perfect, it creates the file and send them to the specify email, however when I try to delete the files

```
if os.path.exists(filename):
    os.remove(filename)

if os.path.exists(filenameZip):
    os.remove(filenameZip)
```

I get the following error:

```
PermissionError at /apptest/sendemailwithattachments/
[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: '00671245sasa-myInstitutionNameHere.zip'
```

Here is the code that I am using to generate the files and send the email

```
myJson = json.dumps(request.data);
filename = sfOppID + "-" + institution + ".json"
file = open(filename,"w")
file.write(myJson)
file.close()

filenameZip = sfOppID + "-" + institution + ".zip"
if myResponse['successFile']:
    file = open(filenameZip,"wb")
    file.write(response.content)
    file.close()

sender_email = "myEmail@hotmail.com"
receiver_email = "receiver@domain.com, " + customenv.otheremail
message = MIMEMultipart()
message["From"] = sender_email
message['To'] = receiver_email
message['Subject'] = "sending mail using python"
attachment = open(filename,'rb')
obj = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
obj.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(obj)
obj.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+filename)
message.attach(obj)

# IF THERE IS A ZIP FILE
if myResponse['successFile']:
    attachment = open(filenameZip,'rb')
    obj = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    obj.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(obj)
    obj.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+filenameZip)
    message.attach(obj)

my_message = message.as_string()
email_session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.live.com',587)
email_session.starttls()
email_session.login(sender_email,'meEmailPassword')
email_session.sendmail(sender_email,receiver_email.split(','),my_message)
email_session.quit()
```

I am wondering what I can do, as the only thing that I can think is scheduling a job to delete this files?

or is there a way to check once the email has been 100% sent and then try to delete the files?

Comment: attachment = open(filename,'rb'), attachment = open(filenameZip,'rb') are not closed

Comment: @TomChen that was it, i cant believe i miss it, would you like to answer this way i can marked my question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close a file whenever you open it.
In your code, you were missing to close files at:

```
attachment = open(filename,'rb')
```

and

```
attachment = open(filenameZip,'rb')
```

If you want to close them automatically, use context manager: [`with`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)